# Make text in link fit perfectly below image

Tags: html, css

I want the text below my images to fit exactly below them. Longer texts continue in the same line which is not I want. I want it to go to the next line and stay below the corresponding image.
I also tried using `break-word` and aligning `center` but it doesn't work.

```css
.row div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
.row div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.row div a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="martial.png">
        </br>Manchester United 2015-16 Martial kit
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="ars.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="bvb.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="lewandowski1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<br />` not `</br>`

Comment: For clarity could you please add image dimensions to the question please? Try using [placehold.it](https://placehold.it/).

Comment: what's wrong with my answer, why did you remove it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gonna have to add additional div container for every image and link.

See the example below:

```css
.row div{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
.row div img{
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
.row div a{
   word-wrap:break-word;
   text-align:center;
}
.img-container{
     display: inline-block;    /* added */
     float: left;            /* added */
     text-align: center;    /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6363634.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Anthony-Martial-signs-for-Manchester-United.jpg"></br>Manchester United 2015-16 Martial kit text aded text aded text aded text aded text aded</a>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="#"><img src="ars.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="#"><img src="bvb.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="#"><img src="lewandowski1.png"></a>
            </div>
</div>
```

If you want to set a predefined width and height you can do it adding rules to `.img-container` class. Other way it will take the image dimensions. And for centered links just add this rule to `.img-container` class:
`text-align: center;`

Comment: The img-container helps @1l13v :)  My images are of fixed sizes so it works only after giving a width to the container.

Comment: yes but I wrote you that you can set width if you want to `.img-container`. I gave you complete solution, I am sorry if you didn't understand it

Comment: i was getting proper result only after explicitly defining a width. It wasnt taking the original image dimensions on its own as you mentioned.

Comment: But I wrote you this:  _If you want to set a predefined width and height you can do it adding rules to .img-container class_

Cheers

Comment: Could you please explain "Other way it will take the image dimensions."

Comment: Divs are block elements and by default they take the entire width of the window, but if you `float` them then they stack next to each other and have the predefined width or the width that fits their content

Comment: So i guess by giving a larger text, the div dimension was getting set to the text length rather than the image width hence i wasnt getting the required output. Adding a width explicitly makes it work perfectly. Thank you for your help .Cheers :)

Comment: Exactly like you said. Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

just give your inner divs a width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .row div {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 40%;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
      //overflow: auto;

    }
    .row div img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    .row div a {
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://e0.365dm.com/15/09/768x432/anthony-martial-manchester-united-press_3345052.jpg?20150904202157">Manchester United 2015-16 Martial fjkghdghjfdhghdfjgjgdfgjhghjhghjgdhjgdhgjdfgdjjhdgjhdffhgfhghdfgjhgdhjdghgfdgjgdfgdfjhjdfgdhjkit</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://e0.365dm.com/15/09/768x432/anthony-martial-manchester-united-press_3345052.jpg?20150904202157">Manchester United 2015-16 Martial fjkghdghjfdhghdfjgjgdfgjhghjhghjgdhjgdhgjdfgdjjhdgjhdffhgfhghdfgjhgdhjdghgfdgjgdfgdfjhjdfgdhjkit</a>
    </div>



  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if the OP wants image to be different sizes?

Comment: @deveshasha just remove text-align from a and put it in div

Comment: Images are of fixed sizes so this works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`min-content`**](http://thenewcode.com/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-MinContent) property on the element containing the `img` and caption. In this demo, I used the `figure` and `figcaption` (and `main`) elements instead of `div`s to create [**semantic**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/semantics) layout. It'll work the same way if you prefer `div's instead.

```css
.row figure {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  /* min-content needs to be prefixed */
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}
.row figure img {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Changed max-* to min-* to demonstrate images in different sizes */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.row figure a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Captions</title>

</head>

<body>
  <main class="row">
    <figure>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/9a7/a10.png&text=Manchester+United+2015-16+Martial+Kit">
        <figcaption>Manchester United 2015-16 Martial Kit</figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/fd3/b0d.png&text=ARS">
        <figcaption>Manchester United 2015-16 Martial Kit</figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100/fa8/375.png&text=BVB">
        <figcaption>Manchester United 2015-16 Martial Kit</figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/048/Fee.png&text=lewandowski1">
        <figcaption>Manchester United 2015-16 Martial Kit</figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```